# when redirecting getting an error malformed header

Tags: python, mysql, apache

the other day i saw in stack overflow how to get redirected using a function..
but its not working here

```
#!/Python27/python
import cgi
import cgitb ; cgitb.enable()
import MySQLdb
from datetime import datetime
f= cgi.FieldStorage()
l=f["roll"].value
def redirect(url):
    print "Content-Type: text/plain"
    print "Refresh: 0; url='%s'" % url
    print
    print "Redirecting..."

Con = MySQLdb.Connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="root", passwd="jesus",        db="student")
cursor = Con.cursor()
sql="SELECT YEAR FROM STDDET WHERE id='%s'"%(l)
cursor.execute(sql)
data=cursor.fetchone()
cyear=datetime.now().year
cmonth=datetime.now().month
data=data[0]
data=int(data)
year=cyear-data
print year
if(year==3):
    redirect("intro.html")
elif(year==4):
     redirect("yea4.html")
```

even though the if condition is satisfied its not getting redirected...am getting an error malformed header...plz help!!

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your script produce the following response:

```
Content-Type: text/plain Refresh: 0; url='x.y.com'

Redirecting...
```

This is not a valid http response since the [status line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is missing.

If you produce a "valid" page, you should reply with a status

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

If you are redirecting, a better idea would be to reply with one of the 3xx code. As an example:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.fr/
```

The `HTTP/1.1 ...` line must be the first of the header. So it should be produced by the first `print` of your program. See [Python CGI returning an http status code, such as 403?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411867/python-cgi-returning-an-http-status-code-such-as-403) for an example.

Comment: can i use http header response to redirect based on a condition...i edited the codee.....can you please tell me whether http header will work for that code?? if not plz help me with an answer