# Running cgi ( Python scripts) in HTML Raspberry Pi using apache

Tags: python, html, apache, raspberry-pi, cgi

I want to be able to run a python script when I press a button in an HTML webpage.
I have followed this example and it works. But when I change the python code to my own I get the following error in the apache/log/error.log:

[Wed Oct 14 01:14:11 2015] [error] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/ha.py' failed
[Wed Oct 14 01:14:11 2015] [error] [client 18.111.23.211] 
Premature end of script headers: ha.py, referer: http://18.111.31.172/page1.html

I followed the tutorial: http://xmodulo.com/create-use-python-cgi-scripts.html
Here is the code for both page1.html and ha.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xbee import XBee,ZigBee
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
list_a=    [b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xC7\x36\x70",b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xC7\x36\x76",b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xE8\x05\xCF"]
address64 = b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xEC\x3B\xEA"
payload = b"\x03"
# Use an XBee 802.15.4 device
# To use with an XBee ZigBee device, replace with:
zb = ZigBee(ser)
#xbee = XBee(ser)

# Set remote DIO pin 2 to low (mode 4)
for i in range(len(list_a)):

print("sending data")
zb.send("tx",dest_addr_long=list_a[i],dest_addr=b"\xFF\xFE",data=payload)


ser.close()
```

and HTML page1.html

```
<html>
<h1>Test Page 1</h1>
<form name="input" action="/cgi-bin/ha.py" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

I changed the html method to "post" from get to see if that would do anything.
All I want to do is run the python code and not change anything to in the html page.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Updated python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xbee import XBee,ZigBee
import serial
print 'Status: 205 No Response'
print ""
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
list_a=[b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xC7\x36\x70",b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xC7\x36\x76",b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xE8\x05\xCF"]
address64 = b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xEC\x3B\xEA"
payload = b"\x03"
# Use an XBee 802.15.4 device
# To use with an XBee ZigBee device, replace with:
zb = ZigBee(ser)
#xbee = XBee(ser)

# Set remote DIO pin 2 to low (mode 4)
for i in range(len(list_a)):

#print("sending data")
    zb.send("tx",dest_addr_long=list_a[i],dest_addr=b"\xFF\xFE",data=payload)


ser.close()
```

update 2: new ha.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
import cgitb
from xbee import XBee,ZigBee
import serial

cgitb.enable()
print 'Status: 205 No Response'
print ""
```

Most current python script: 
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import cgi
import cgitb
from xbee import XBee,ZigBee
import serial

cgitb.enable()
#print 'Status: 205 No Response'
#print ""
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<h1>Hello World</h1>"

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
list_a=[b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xC7\x36\x70",b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xC7\x36\x76",b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xE8\x05\xCF"]
address64 = b"\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xEC\x3B\xEA"
payload = b"\x03"
# Use an XBee 802.15.4 device
# To use with an XBee ZigBee device, replace with:
zb = ZigBee(ser)
#xbee = XBee(ser)

# Set remote DIO pin 2 to low (mode 4)
for i in range(len(list_a)):

#print("sending data")
    zb.send("tx",dest_addr_long=list_a[i],dest_addr=b"\xFF\xFE",data=payload)


ser.close()
```

and I get this new error: (see image)
Any help?[image]

I tried this fix i found an it doesn't work:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=82779

Comment: Where are you outputting the headers?

Comment: What do you mean? What headers ?

Comment: The headers that you need to output for every CGI script ever.

Comment: I followed the tutorial from: http://xmodulo.com/create-use-python-cgi-scripts.html I didn't know that you have to output headers. Can you help me out?

Comment: Start reading from "The contents of /var/www/cgi-bin/myscript-1.py are:".

Comment: Oh I see thank you.  " The print "Content-Type: text/html" statement is required so that the web server knows what type of output it is receiving from the CGI script" The issue is that i don't want to output anything. I juts want the python script to run.

Comment: Then a) you need to not print anything, and b) you need to tell the browser to not expect anything via the correct status code.

Comment: So not print anything in the python code? How exactly do I do b? I've been reading this http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html and I don't quite understand it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411867/python-cgi-returning-an-http-status-code-such-as-403

Comment: Would I then send: print 'Status: 204 No Response'? For the method would I then change that to 'get'? thanks!

Comment: The GET method results in a change in the URL shown in the browser. Also, you should consider if 205 might be more appropriate. And don't forget the blank line.

Comment: I've had done the following changes and I still get no results. Any other tips? Still get the following error: [Wed Oct 14 02:11:44 2015] [error] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/ha.py' failed
[Wed Oct 14 02:11:44 2015] [error] [client 18.111.23.211] Premature end of script headers: ha.py, referer: http://18.111.31.172/page1.html

Comment: Did you forget the blank line?

Comment: Then one of your imports is probably failing. See the `cgitb` module documentation.

Comment: But in python I'm using "import cgi" not "import cgitb" does that matter ?

Comment: Im currently reading this: http://raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/writing-cgi-scripts-in-python.htmlm the debugging python code

Comment: How exactly does cgitb work? should i then print a line like: print "Content-Type: text/plain"

Comment: I have also switch the python script and it seems to work: the new python script has the following: #!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

print "<h1>Hello World</h1>"

Comment: I think it is an issue with not sending anything and having the "get" in the method. I have changed the script to the following( see above under update 2)